# Hackerrank Day 8: Dictionaries and Maps problem (Python used)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

**Objective**
Today, we're learning about Key-Value pair mappings using a Map or Dictionary data structure. Check out the Tutorial tab for learning materials and an instructional video!

**Task**
Given  names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each  queried, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for  is not found, print Not found instead.

**Note: Your phone book should be a Dictionary/Map/HashMap data structure.**

**Input Format**
The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of entries in the phone book.
Each of the  subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of  space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's name, and the second value is an -digit phone number.
After the  lines of phone book entries, there are an unknown number of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a  to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

**Note: Names consist of lowercase English alphabetic letters and are first names only.**

**Output Format**
On a new line for each query, print Not found if the name has no corresponding entry in the phone book; otherwise, print the full  and  in the format name=phoneNumber.

**Sample Input**

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

**Sample Output**

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933
```

**MY CODE:**

```
# No. of dictionary inputs
n = int(input())

# Code to fill the phonebook with entries
phonebook = {}
for _ in range(1, n+1):
  entry = input().split(" ")
    
  phonebook[entry[0]] = entry[1]

# Code for query intake
queries = []
while(1):
  queries.append(input())

  #need to figure out when the user stops input and need to break this loop then
  if (input() == ""):
    break

# Code for query result
for i in range(0, len(queries)):
  if(queries[i] in phonebook):
    print(queries[i] + "=" + phonebook[queries[i]])
    # print(f"{queries[i]}={phonebook[queries[i]]}")
  else:
    print("Not found")
```

**Issue faced by me:**
When I run the code, I put the sample input, everything runs fine till the end, however, while printing out the result, the query "edward" doesn't get an output.
The desired output for "edward" would be "Not Found" however, every even input is getting missed, probably due to the if statement in the while loop.

Comment: If your question is specific to Python 2, please don't use the [tag:python-3.x] tag. If it's specific to Python 3, please don't use the [tag:python-2.7] tag (or suggest in your title that this is a Python 2 issue). If it's not specific to either, please don't use either of those tags. You can read more about how to tag Python questions in the [Python tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> while(1):
>   queries.append(input())
>
>   #need to figure out when the user stops input and need to break this loop then
>   if (input() == ""):
>     break
> ```

should use `input()` only once, and then either `append()` or `break`:

```
while True:
  line = input()
  if line == "":
    break
  queries.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Final code that worked, **without an EOF error as I handled it using try except block:**

```
# Code to fill the phonebook with entries
phonebook = dict() #Declare a dictionary
for _ in range(int(input())):
    key, value = input().split()
    
    phonebook[key] = value

#Trick - If there is no more input stop the program
try:
    # Code for query intake
    queries = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line == "":
            break
        queries.append(line)
except Exception:
    pass

# Code for query result
for i in range(0, len(queries)):
    if(queries[i] in phonebook):
        print(queries[i] + "=" + phonebook[queries[i]])
        # print(f"{queries[i]}={phonebook[queries[i]]}")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```